# Right headlight, Right window, petrol Cap,rear right light

Tags: electrical, vw, golf

I have a problem with my golf 5 1.6,petrol Cap it's not opening,the right window is not working,the headlight of right side it's not lighting but the globe its not burned,as well as the rear right light isn't working, what can cause all this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year is your Golf?

Comment: Sounds like a bad ground wire connection somewhere... and you guessed it.. somewhere on the right side of the car.

Comment: 2005 model, hatchback

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing somewhere there is a loose ground connection.  Rarely do these things fail like that.  My guess is loose bolt.  The problem, of course is finding it.  It may be in the engine compartment, in the passenger compartment behind the instrument panel or under the carpeting on a side panel.  I'd guess there are eight to ten different grounding locations on your car.

[image: Ground Connection]

It may look something like this.  It may well be a copper terminal.  It may well have three or more wires crimped to it. The bolt holding that to the sheet metal should be secure.

The problem of course is finding the culprit.  Best way is to obtain a wiring diagram of your specific vehicle and trace the circuits on paper looking for a common ground (or possible power supply point.) I will say obtaining such a diagram can be difficult.  Not sure what is available in your area.  I'd start with the VW dealer.

And I'm assuming there are no aftermarket modifications made to your car by either you or the dealer (no add ons for security or audio or aftermarket options?) . If so, start with the added on stuff first.  Some of that work, if done poorly, can cause problems in the electrical system.